# Boostrap - Dropdown menu in pulled-right navbar section displays panel arrow on the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, trying to create a Facebook like top navbar for an ecommerce. I'm adding a dropdown to the far right top link, so the link "Account" shows a dropdown for account related actions.

The dropdown menu is nicely aligned right, but the little arrow that appears on top of the menu panel is left aligned, pointing to a previous link in the navbar.

To see it, please see this fiddle (fullscreen to stop the navbar from collapsing): 
http://jsfiddle.net/v3wgt/1/embedded/result/

And the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3wgt/2/

Is there any fix / workaround / alternative to this?

Comment: Can't answer my own question, but I was missing class `nav pull-right` on the *parent* UL.

Comment: Was just about to post that answer :P, the bootstrap already does that automatically for you, all you have to do is add the `pull-right` class to the menu `<ul class="nav">` itself, and you can approve your own answer it just takes a few hours so post it and approve it when you can.

Comment: Thanks Andres, I had to wait 8 hours and I hope to be *not* working by that time! Should have checked the samples in deep, my bad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for completeness, the solution was to add the `pull-right` class to the parent UL, like this:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
   ... your links here
   <li class="dropdown">your dropdown item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The class on the `div` surrounding the `navigation` should be just `nav` instead of `nav-collapse` -> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csuXw/) (html area line 5)

Comment: Thanks Matthias but that was not the issue really. See my own answer below.

Comment: The arrow was also moving to the right on my changes ^^. Anyway good that you solved it.